# How to use `launch.json` on VSCode for making shortcut for running C++ program?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw, vscode-tasks

I'm using VSCode and MinGW for C++ coding and I want to set a shortcut for build and run C++ program. I can build C++ program and run the created .exe file successively just by `F1 -> C/C++ : Build and Debug Active file->  g++.exe` in one time, and I want to set a shortcut for this.
The ordinary way seems to be setting tasks of build on `tasks.json` file and tasks of run on `launch.json` file. I saw [this document](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558) about tasks.json and launch.json but I could not understand at all because it was too technical for me.(I'm very new to things around compiling)
Fortunately, about `tasks.json`, the command palette of VSCode provides `Task: Configure Default Build Task` menu which automatically write appropriate settings into `tasks.json`. However, about `launch.json`, I cannot find such a kind automation menu. Does that mean I need to write in the `launch.json` on my own? If I had some documents for for `launch.json`, the task would be easy.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Comment: Thank you. I would use it as reference.